# how to define multi parameter with from function in rust

Tags: rust

Now I want to map object from `Favorites` to `FavMusicResponse`, the `Favorites` object was selected from database and the `FavMusicResponse` entity was return to the client.  I define the map function like this way in `FavMusicResponse`:

```
impl From<&Favorites> for FavMusicResponse {
    fn from(f: &Favorites, music: Music) -> Self {
        Self{
            id: f.id,
            song_id: None,
            created_time: f.created_time,
            updated_time: f.updated_time,
            user_id: 0,
            source_id: "".to_string(),
            like_status: 0,
            source: 0,
            playlist_id: 0,
            play_count: 0,
            fetched_download_url: None,
            downloaded: None,
            music: Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

most of the fields from `Favorites` fields are the same with `FavMusicResponse`, the only difference is that music was passed from another entity. This is my `FavMusicResponse` define:

```
#[derive( Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize,Default, Clone)]
pub struct FavMusicResponse{
    pub id: i64,
    pub song_id: Option<i64>,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub source_id: String,
    pub like_status: i32,
    pub source: i32,
    pub playlist_id: i64,
    pub play_count: i32,
    pub fetched_download_url: Option<i32>,
    pub downloaded: Option<i32>,
    pub music: Music
}
```

the compiler tell me that from `expected 1 parameter, found 2`, what should I do do pass 2 or more parameter into the composite function in rust? I invoke the function like this way:

```
let filtered_music:Vec<_> = musics.iter()
            .filter(|item| item.source_id == fav.source_id)
            .map(|item|FavMusicResponse::from(fav,item.clone()))
            .collect();
```

I want to passed two entity and composite to the finally  `FavMusicResponse` entity. what should I do to make it work like that? This is my minimal reproduce that could run in rust playground to figure out where is going wrong:

```
fn main() {
    let music = Music{
        id: 1
    };
    let favMusic = Favorites{
        id: 1
    };
    let musicRes = FavMusicResponse::from(favMusic,music);
}

pub struct Music {
    pub id: i64
}

pub struct Favorites {
    pub id: i64
}

pub struct FavMusicResponse {
    pub id: i64,
    pub music:Music
}


impl From<Favorites> for FavMusicResponse {
    fn from(f: Favorites, music: Music) -> Self {
        Self{
            id: f.id,
            music: music
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, I have added the minimal reproduce. @Stargateur

Comment: You can't do this with `From` because you clearly need another piece of information - a value of type `Music` to transform from one type to the another. Just write your own custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait can't take two parameters only one, it's define that way, the only solution if you really want to use `From` trait is to transform your two parameter into one, a quick solution is to use a `tuple`:

```rust
impl From<(Favorites, Music)> for FavMusicResponse {
    fn from((f, music): (Favorites, Music)) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: f.id,
            music,
        }
    }
}

// let musicRes = FavMusicResponse::from((favMusic, music));
```

That said you could also just have a `new()` method on your type:

```rust
impl FavMusicResponse {
    fn new(f: Favorites, music: Music) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: f.id,
            music,
        }
    }
}

// let musicRes = FavMusicResponse::new(favMusic, music);
```